# Start playing an audio file when application goes in background

Tags: ios, background, avaudioplayer

**It's like "Google Maps" navigate in the background.**

I have added "App plays audio" to "Required background modes" already, but it doesn't work.
What's wrong with it?

Here is the sample source code:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];

BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;

if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
{
    backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
}
if (backgroundSupported && _bgTask==UIBackgroundTaskInvalid )
{
    UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        while (app.applicationState==UIApplicationStateBackground && _bgTask!=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
        {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
            [self playAudio];
        }

        [app endBackgroundTask:_bgTask];
        _bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
}

-(void)playAudio {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];  

NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sound" withExtension:@"caf"];
NSError *error;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
[self.audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
 [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

---

The url of audio file maybe is from web, and will play multiple audio file in a queue.

Comment: Can you try removing the line [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay]; and try it again?   And also can you please let us know if you tried debugging and if the playAudio method is called...

Comment: It's still not working after remove  [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];  Why should remove it?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's doc on the subject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a):

> Because it's likely any background tasks you start in
>   applicationDidEnterBackground: will not run until after that method
>   exits, you should request additional background execution time before
>   starting those tasks. In other words, first call
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and then run the task on a
>   dispatch queue or secondary thread.

From my own experience of playing background audio, if you don't request extra time you need to set things up beforehand so that `[self.audioPlayer play]` is literally the first line of code in `applicationDidEnterBackground`, otherwise the system suspends the app before the audio has a chance to kick in and keep it awake.